# $.ajax para de funcionar os outros scripts em jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Uso está função para chamar uma página:

```
$('#selector1').on('change',function(){
    $.ajax({
            type      : 'post',
            url       : 'servico_institucional.php', // aqui eu indico qual o arquivo que vai ser enviado essa variavel retorno
            data      : 'retorno='+$("#selector1").val,  //Cara, aqui eu pego o valor do input com o ID AJAX_INPUT E passo para uma variavel chamada    retorno
            dataType  : 'html',
            success : function(response){
                $('.form-servico').html(response);
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert("Erro!");
            }
    }); 
});
```

Porém, quando chamo a página, os outros scripts `jquery` param de funcionar. Exemplo: scripts do menu, de responsividade entre outros.

Como consertar este problema?

Comment: tente passar no seu data, o valor assim $("#selector1").val()

Comment: Deve estar dando um erro no js. Você já debugou?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fala, Diego! Blz?

Use o eval() para executar os scripts.

```
$('#selector1').on('change',function(){ 
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        context: document.body,
        url: 'servico_institucional.php',
        data: 'retorno='+$("#selector1").val,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(response){
            $('.form-servico').html(response);
            $('.form-servico').find('script').each(function(i) {
                eval($(this).text());
            });
        }, error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Erro!");
        }
    });
});
```

Se tiver dúvidas sobre o funcionamento da função, veja esse artigo da W3Schools:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

Abraço!

Comment: Estou tendo um problema meio parecido aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146486/7759 mas eu não sei como fazer isso, no meu caso terei que chamar o arquivo rodape.inc.php(onde estão os scripts) sempre que trocar de URL via ajax?