# JavaScript PushState/PopState desabilita outros scripts

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho esse código no meu site js/pushstate.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var nav, conteudo, fetchAndInsert;

//nav = $('div#navbar');
nav = $('.menu');
conteudo = $('#conteudo');

fetchAndInsert = function(href) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://somdomato.com/cont/' + href.split('/').pop(),
        method: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            conteudo.html(data);
        }
    });
};

$(window).on('popstate', function() {
    fetchAndInsert(location.pathname);
});

nav.find('a').on('click', function(e) {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    history.pushState(null, null, href);
    fetchAndInsert(href);
    e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

/index.php:

```
<?php require 'inc/cabecalho.inc.php'; ?>

<div id="conteudo">
    <?php require 'cont/index.php'; ?>
</div>

<?php require 'inc/rodape.inc.php'; ?>
```

O script funciona normal e as páginas são carregadas sem o player parar de tocar a música e o endereço muda conforme o esperado.

O problema é que quando eu troco de uma página para outra todos os outros scripts param de funcionar.

A url é http://somdomato.com 
Alguem tem uma idéia do que pode estar acontecendo?

Obrigado.

Comment: Tentei fazer isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/117454/7759 mas eu não entendi muito bem o procedimento, e acho que não funcionou.